# No se cargan todas las imagenes en JavFX

Tags: javafx

Estoy utilizando este codigo para cargar varias imagenes estilo una galeria desde una carpeta, el problema es que no salen todas. He probado cargar la misma imagen repetida y pasa lo mismo.

```
 Set<Node> imagesViews =  vBoxGallery.lookupAll(".img");
    File imageFile;
    for (final Node imgView: imagesViews) {
        imageFile = new File("gallery/img/"+imgView.getId()+".jpg");
        String url = imageFile.toURI().toString();
        Image image = new Image(url,true);
        ((ImageView)imgView).setImage(image);

        imgView.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(MouseEvent event) {
                VisorImage visor = new VisorImage(((ImageView)imgView).getImage());
                visor.show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Necesitas un contenedor al cual ir añadiendo las imágenes dentro del bucle, [por ejemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27184788/5587982).

Comment: Gracias, de mucha ayuda.